# when I am trying to launch my app in my device and I am getting the error as launch option nil in my xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I am getting nil for the launchOptions in the following method .

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   return true     
   }
```

**And the app crashes,what should I do now? If anybody knows help me!**

I have attached the screenshot of my console.

[image: screenshot of console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

launchoptions has the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey is the one that signifies and has values when your app is launched from some action like openURL, notification etc.

Please have a look at link http://nshipster.com/launch-options/ for further info.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below method :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

Comment: @abishek what is the reason for getting launchOptions as nil value?